# combine spring batch and spring integration?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-batch, spring-integration

thanks for attention,i defined a combine spring batch and spring integration project and communicate with ftp server to retrieve file and process on it and write on ftp, i am looking for a good architecture for my project, i designed an architecture with spring integration as bellow diagram:
[image]

when retrieve file from server process on it and route files based on condition to mvChannel and toGet channel, i have many process scenario on the retrieved file from server that i defined a router that router handle the scenario , and route to job channels and run spring batch
now, my is question is that are right the architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really looks good. It is is typical pattern to get gain from both Spring Integration and Spring Batch worlds integration them.

However I don't see reason in the last `<aggregator>`. All your jobs can send their result to the `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway command="PUT">`. Looks like no need to wait for all results to do some analysis on them in the single place.